# Prove that $e^{x}-2\cos(x) = 0$ where $x\in(0,1)$ has solution.

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity

Prove that $e^{x}-2\cos(x) = 0$ where $x\in(0,1)$ has solution for $x$.

I'd like to do this without derivatives, just using limit definition and function continuity.

To begin, we could rewrite this as two functions:
$f(x) = e^{x}$ and $g(x) = 2\cos(x)$. I can simply draw the plot, but it isn't a real proof. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: $e^x - 2 \cos x$ evaluates to $-1$ at $x = 0$ and $e$ at $x = 1$. By the intermediate value theorem, ____.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f(x) = e^x - 2\cos x$ has $f(0) = 1 - 2 = -1 < 0$, and $f(1) = e - 2\cos 1 > e - 2 > 0$. So by IVT, there is $c \in (0, 1)$ so that $f(c) = 0$.

Answer (score 5):

Hint: A certain intermediate value theorem might be of use here.

Comment: Do I have to prove, that $e^{x}$ and $\cos(x)$ is continuous? Or is it commonly known and doesn't need explaination?

Comment: If you want to prove it, you could show that they are differentiable, and $D \implies C$.